# Adding a label to stat_mean in ggscatter

Tags: r, plot, scatter

I'm looking at [ggpubr::stat_mean](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggpubr/versions/0.4.0/topics/stat_mean):

Is there a way to add a label on top of the group mean point indicating the groping label cyl? Thanks!

[reproducible example:]

```
# Load data
library(ggpubr)
df <- mtcars
df$cyl <- as.factor(df$cyl)

# Scatter plot with ellipses and group mean points
ggscatter(df, x = "wt", y = "mpg",
          color = "cyl", shape = "cyl", ellipse = TRUE)+
  stat_mean(aes(color = cyl, shape = cyl), size = 4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit unclear to me how you would do that with `ggpubr`. For some reason it doesn't seem to like to let you use the geom_text with `stat_mean`.

One work around is just to use `ggplot` directly with a bit of `dplyr` to calculate the means. You can do

```
library(dplyr)

means <- df %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarize(across(c(wt, mpg), mean))

ggplot(df)  +
  aes(x=wt, y=mpg, color=cyl, shape=cyl) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_ellipse(aes(fill=cyl), alpha=.2, geom="polygon") + 
  geom_point(size=4, data=means) + 
  geom_label(aes(label=cyl), color="black", nudge_y =2.5, data=means) + 
  ggpubr::theme_pubr()
```

to get
[image: added label to group means]

Comment: Thanks, I think this should be the way to go, as you say. However, I don't understand why we need means to have more than the CYL means. I was trying with my data creating a means dataframe having just one column (cyl) with the means, but it complains.

Comment: I have fixed it now, one more question: is it possible to hide the ellipses?

Comment: If you don’t want the ellipses, take out the stat_ellipse() line

Comment: I have fixed it now, one more question: is it possible to remove the white background from the labels (have it transparent?)

Comment: Use geom_text() rather than geom_label()

Comment: I have another question, shall I create a new post? It's about repelling the labels. In my plot they overlap. Thanks.